# Cloudwatch Alarm Based on A Kinesis Metric not Triggered When Value is Over The Threshold

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, cloudwatch-alarms

## Issue Description

We have a AWS Cloudwatch alarm that's very clearly gone over the threshold line indicated in the metric graph that's being monitored but it didn't trigger.

[image]

What is going on here? How can an alarm clearly go over the threshold for way longer than it's period and evaluation time and not trigger?

## Alarm Configuration and Empty History

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the settings for the alarm there's two very interesting things of note.

[image]

The first interesting thing is that the alarm is in the `Insufficient Data` state for a continuous line graph.

The second is that the alarm is configured for seconds as the unit and the above graph shows milliseconds. And in fact if we list a set of metrics for the iterator age

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace "AWS/Lambda" --metric-name "IteratorAge" --dimensions Name=FunctionName,Value=prod-pipeline-rules-exec --statistics Maximum --start-time $(gdate -u -d '20 minutes ago' +%Y-%m-%dT%TZ) --end-time $(gdate -u +%Y-%m-%dT%TZ) --period 60 --region <region>
    [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2019-12-18T01:43:00Z",
            "Maximum": 2327.0,
            "Unit": "Milliseconds"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2019-12-18T01:25:00Z",
            "Maximum": 2188.0,
            "Unit": "Milliseconds"
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2019-12-18T01:34:00Z",
            "Maximum": 2459.0,
            "Unit": "Milliseconds"
        }
    ]
```

The units are in Milliseconds.

Unfortunately, Cloudwatch will treat unit mismatches as missing data and this will lead to your alarms never triggering.

Comment: Just curious, how did you create this alarm? AWS Console, CloudFormation or API call?

Comment: In our case we made this alarm via terraform and if you don't specify a unit it defaults to seconds.

Comment: That's a dangerous default. CloudWatch docs say 'We recommend omitting Unit so that you don't inadvertently specify an incorrect unit that is not published for this metric. Doing so causes the alarm to be stuck in the INSUFFICIENT DATA state.' Might be good to communicate this to the Terraform people.

Comment: Also, CloudWatch probably shouldn't display a graph if they can't find the data for the alarm.

Comment: @UnkindnessofDatapoints Super solid points. I'll go open a ticket against terraform and update my AWS support ticket.